# Devise create guest records/user results in email can't be blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I am currently trying to add guest users/records to my application and am encountering having some difficulty getting devise to play along. I am trying to follow the tutorial at http://railscasts.com/episodes/393-guest-user-record, but am stuck when it comes to bypassing the devise validation for the email, password, and username if the user is a guest. In the video tutorial at about 5:40 he quickly mentions devise but i am lost as to how to implement this change. Thanks for the help.

Update** Here is my code. Thanks for the help guys.

Here is my create action under my users_controller.rb

```
def create  
  @user = params[:user] ? User.new(params[:user]) : User.new_guest  
    if @user.save  
      current_user.move_to(@user) if current_user && current.user.guest?  
      session[:user_id] = @user.id  
      redirect_to root_url  
    else  
      render "new"  
  end  
end
```

Here is code from my user.rb

```
validates_presence_of :username, unless: :guest?
validates_uniqueness_of :username, :email, allow_blank: true
```

Here is the link that starts the Guest Record

```
<%= button_to "Try it!", users_path, method: :post %>
```

The errors that I am getting is are

```
3 errors prohibited this user from being saved:
Email can't be blank
Password can't be blank
Username can't be blank
```

Comment: What are you trying, what's not working, what errors do you get, etc... we aren't magicians here dude

Comment: Have you got `before_filter :authenticate_user!` in your controller?

Comment: Hi Rich, I have added before_filter :authenticate_user! to my User Controller but It did not change any of the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You may be receiving the “can't be blank” errors as the parameters are not being allowed through the Devise controller as they're not listed as permitted params?

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters

Check for 'Unpermitted parameters' errors in your logs to see if this is the issue.